# Chrome randomly stops scrolling for a few seconds on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, scrolling

When I scroll down or up in a Chrome page, it get stucks sometimes for a three to six seconds I cannot move anymore in the page. I found that very annoying.

Here are the caracteristics of my system :
- last version of Max OS X with Sierra (10.12.2) (the bug was happening too with previous versions Yosemite)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)
- Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)

Comment: Does the content of the page make any difference? For instance, if you have a page of simple text versus a page with video and ads and dynamic content, does one hang and the other not?

Comment: Yes I did not see any thing specific about the content, it is random.

Comment: One thing to check and two things to try: Does this happen more often when there are more tabs open or fewer? Update drivers for your computer, especially graphics drivers, and try disabling hardware acceleration in Google Chrome: http://ccm.net/faq/35743-google-chrome-how-to-disable-hardware-acceleration